# Xamarin Forms iOS11 Large Title text Extra Blank space

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms, ios11

I am trying to update my app to support iOS 11 Large Texts feature. In my custom Navigation Page renderer I have set 
NavigationBar.PrefersLargeTitles = true;
[image]

The Large Title texts are displayed fine and on scroll they get smaller too.
However on scroll when the Large Title becomes smaller, I am seeing an extra white space at the bottom. (Highlighted in the attached screen shot).
I have read and browsed a lot of posts regarding the issue but my bad luck that none of them works.

I am pretty sure someone would have encountered the error and would have found a workaround or it's solution.
I have also posted the same question in Xamarin Forums but no responses.
https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/104457/xamarin-forms-ios11-large-title-text-extra-blank-space

Comment: I tried in iOS with Xcode , it works perfectly without blank space, but in xamarin.forms i'm facing the same problem as you.Maybe it's the issue with xamarin, I suggest you  report it to xamarin develop team.

Comment: Yes looks like it's with xamarin. I will raise it as bug to xamarin team.

Comment: https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=60054

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of Xamarin Forms - 2.5.0.91635. This issue is resolved.

For any queries follow the thread on Xamarin Forums -
https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/307295